# How to describe an ontology to infer wheather two individuals are the same or not

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, inference, rdfs

I would like to infer wheather two individuals are the same or not.
I show you three cases. In the first case I described an ontology to get the result of inference which means “If two individuals have the same value of a property then two individuals are the same”. A description of the case is below.

```
Person rdf:type owl:Class .
ID rdf:type owl:Class .
hasID rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ,
               owl:InverseFunctionalProperty .
person1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person ;
        hasID id1 .
person2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person;
        hasID id1 .
id1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
             ID .
```

The result of inference is “person1 owl: sameAs person2”, because person1 and person2 have the same value of hasID which is id1. The key point to get an expected result is what I described hasID as owl:InverseFunctionalProperty. It's not problem.

In the second case two individual have the same two properties. One property is hasName. The another is mailTo. I would like to get the result of inference which means “If two individuals have the same value of hasName ***and*** the same value of mailTo then two individuals are the same”. However I don’t know how to describe an ontology.
How do I describe about it?

The third case is more complicated. How do I describe "the same value of hasID ***or*** the conjunction that means "the same value of hasName ***and*** the same value of mailTo" on ontology?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F9:_Keys - if that's not sufficient enough, just use SWRL

Comment: I tried to describe an ontologuy using hasKey. I described hasID as key for one class and hasName and mailTo as key for the another class. Subsequently, I describe a class which is intersection of one and the another class and set three individuals for each class. The result of inference was expected. Thank you!

Comment: if you found the solution, please provide it here as an answer and also accept your own answer. This helps others as well and marks the topic being resolved

Comment: Sure. Please wait for a while.

Comment: I found the solution. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer of the third case is below.

```
#  Data properties

hasID rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .
hasName rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .
mailTo rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty .

#  Class
Person rdf:type owl:Class ;
       owl:hasKey ( hasID
                  ) ,
                  ( hasName
                    mailTo
                  ) .

#  Individuals
person1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person ;
        hasID 12 ;
        hasName "Donald" ;
        mailTo "D_Trump@ex.com" .
person2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person ;
        hasID 12 ;
        hasName "Don" ;
        mailTo "D_Trump@ex.com" .
person3 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person ;
        hasID 34 ;
        hasName "Bill" ;
        mailTo "B_Clinton@ex.com" .
person4 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person ;
        hasID 56 ;
        hasName "Bill" ;
        mailTo "B_Clinton@ex.com" .
person5 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person ;
        hasID 78 ;
        hasName "Don" ;
        mailTo "D_Trump@ex.com" .
person6 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 Person ;
        hasID 90 ;
        hasName "Barack" ;
        mailTo "B_Obama@ex.com" .
```

Look at "owl:hasKey" in class expression above. Properties in a couple of parenthesis are components of a key. Therefore `owl:hasKey (hasName mailTo)` means "hasName ***and*** mailTo". A couple of parenthesis means independent key. Specifically,"hasID" and "hasName and mailTo" independently work as key. It means "***or***".
I tried the code above, using Pellet on Protege5.5.0 and could get an expected result.Specifically, person1,person2 and person5 are the same, person3 and person4 are the same, and person6 does not have any same individual.